# How to construct an abelian permutation group?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, abelian-groups

I am studying binary operations and permutation groups.
One of the exercices leaves me a bit perplex, that is:

"Construct a permutation group which is Abelian(commutative)"

From what I understand, a permutation group is the set of all possible permutations on a set of numbers? What does the question mean?

Thanks for answering me !

Edit: -- Actually, I am unsure about how the answer is supposed to look like - is a permutation group simply a permutation (ex. (1 2 3)(4 5) ) ?

Comment: Using your language:  "Find a set of numbers whose permutation group is an Abelian group."  I'd recommend looking for small sets as then the proofs are manageably short.

Comment: I guess it may mean a subgroup of  $S_n$ for some $n$. For $S_n$ to be commutative, there are not many choices…

Comment: Generally the group of _all_ permutations of a set of numbers is called a "symmetric group", and a _subgroup_ of a symmetric group is a "permutation group". Every group is isomorphic to a permutation group, given by its action on itself by left multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Cayley's Theorem, every group may be viewed as a permutation group. So you can just choose any abelian group $A$ and look at it as a permutation group. The proof of the Cayley's Theorem is a good hint for you. More precisely, for every $a \in A$, define $\lambda_a : G \to G$ with $\lambda_a(x) = ax$. Then $\{\lambda_a | a \in G \}$ is a subgroup of $S_{|G|}$ isomorphic to $A$ (if you don't know the Cayley's Theorem, you should try to prove this part).

**Example.** Assume that $A = \{e,a,b,c\}$ is the Klein group. We know that $ab = c$, $ac = b$ and $bc = a$. So we may write:

$$\lambda _a  = \left( \begin{gathered}
  e\,\,\,a\,\,\,\,b\,\,\,\,\,c \hfill \\
  a\,\,\,\,e\,\,\,\,c\,\,\,b \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) = (e\,\,\,a)(b\,\,c)$$
Similarly, $
\lambda _b  = (e\,\,\,b)(a\,\,c)$ and $\lambda _c  = (e\,\,\,c)(a\,\,b)$.